# What kind of manifold is one with a trivial tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which manifolds are parallelizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/which-manifolds-are-parallelizable)

This question is all about vector bundles isomorphic to trivial ones (for the sake of completeness I've collected definitions I refer to below). Let us agree to call *trivial* those bundles too.

> **Question** What does characterize manifolds with a trivial tangent bundle?

At first I would have thought that such a manifold must be somewhat "dull", like a Euclidean space. But let us consider the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ and the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$. The first is not a Euclidean space and still has a trivial tangent bundle. The second has not a trivial tangent bundle, for the existance of a vector bundle isomorphism $F \colon \rm{T}\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$ would contradict the [Hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). (cfr. Spivak *A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry*, chapter 3).

This little example induces me to think that there must be more behind this. Can someone add something?

---

A quick review of definitions:

A *vector bundle* is a five-tuple $(E, B, V, \pi)$ where $E, B$ are topological spaces, $V$ is a vector space, $\pi\colon E \to B$ is surjective and continuous, every fibre of $\pi$ has a vector space structure and a *local triviality* condition is satisfied (for every $p\in B$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ and a homeomorphism $t \colon \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times V$ whose restriction to each fiber is a linear isomorphism). The vector bundle $(B \times V, B, V, \pi_1)$ is called *trivial*.

If $(E, B, V, \pi)$ and $(E', B', V', \pi')$ are vector bundles, a pair of continuous functions $(\tilde{f}, f)$ such that the following diagram commutes

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
E & \ra{\tilde{f}} & E' \\
\da{\pi} & & \da{\pi'} \\
B & \ra{f} & B' \\
\end{array}
$$
and the restriction of $\tilde{f}$ to every fiber is linear is called a *vector bundle map*. A bijective vector bundle map whose inverse is still a vector bundle map is called a *vector bundle isomorphism*.

Comment: I think the word for this is [parallelizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold).

Comment: @Dylan @Theo: Ok! Now I know which word to look for. Thank you!

Comment: @Theo: that's not entirely true. H spaces are known to have trivial tangent sphere bundle, but apparently they [can have non-trivial tangent bundles](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51593/).

Comment: In any case, let's wait and see if Ryan Budney will pop over and comment on this question.

Comment: @Willie: Thanks! I knew there was something not quite right here... So let me restate the correct part again to avoid spreading misinformation: Lie groups are parallelizable as can be seen by identifying the Lie algebra with the left-invariant vector fields.

Comment: This looks awfully similar to a question I asked a while ago. So in case you haven't seen it yet: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/which-manifolds-are-parallelizable

Comment: @Marek: In fact I had not seen your question. Mine is a complete duplicate of yours so I'm going to delete it in the next two hours. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @dissonance: Why delete it? It would be sufficient if the question is closed as a duplicate (I just cast my vote).

Comment: @Theo: I voted to close too. I didn't know of this option in case of duplicate questions!

Comment: I've closed the question.

Comment: One advantage about duplicates is that, for example, if another user comes along and knows about the notion of a trivial tangent bundle but does not know the terminology "parallelizable", having your question here as a duplicate (rather than deleted) will allow him/her to more easily find the answer.