# When is the frame bundle of a manifold trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry

My question is what are the topological restrictions on a manifold $M$ such that its frame bundle is trivial?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/which-manifolds-are-parallelizable, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50127/what-kind-of-manifold-is-one-with-a-trivial-tangent-bundle?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manifold with this property is called [parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold) or frameable. A necessary condition is that all of its [characteristic classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class) (e.g. Stiefel-Whitney, Pontryagin) vanish; in particular, $M$ must be orientable and, if closed, must have Euler characteristic $0$ by the [Poincare-Hopf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem). In dimensions divisible by $4$ and for closed $M$ we also get that the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(topology)) of $M$ vanishes by the [signature theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence#L_genus_and_the_Hirzebruch_signature_theorem).

For example, among the closed orientable surfaces $\Sigma_g$, only $\Sigma_1 = T^2$, the torus, is frameable, because it's the only one with Euler characteristic $0$.