# String and BString

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fiber-bundles

In [one of the talks](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/TALKS/ThomTalk.pdf) of J.P. May he mentioned some examples of structure groups and their classification spaces (he mentioned: O, U, SO, SU, Sp, Spin, String, Top, STop, F and SF). Most of them are familiar with me, but I never heard of the structure group String. Googling isn't helping much, because you always find yourself reading some physics article. The question is simple:

- What does the group $String$ mean in the context of fibre bundles?
- In what articles / books are they explained ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46306/152. But there is a problem here: String is *not* a Lie group.

Comment: Some explanations: http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/10/string_and_fivebranestructures.html (and links there)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is really useful. To be complete, the new article http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0810/0810.2131v1.pdf (also obtainable from the golem site gives some deeper insites. I have also read about a FiveBrane structure groups, whicht sits in $\ldots \leftarrow Spin(n) \leftarrow String(n) \leftarrow FiveBrane(n)$. I don't know about groups beyond FiveBrane(n), but probably this sequence can be added indefinetly, if meaningful. Probably the neme FiveBrane stems from connections with Brane Theory. so in retrospect, I wonder what is beyond that...

Comment: To answer my own question (not really a proof, but a mere observation): Looking at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Fivebrane+group and the celebrated Bott-periodicity, I think there is nothing beyond the FiveBrane(n) group, but please do correct me.

Comment: Why, there is an infinite Postnikov tower (FiveBrane is a 7-connected cover but there is a 8-connected cover and so on).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [nLab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+structure)

Comment: Thanks for your usefuk remark. I shall put nLab in my favorites.