# Which compact (orientable) surfaces are parallelizable?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Which compact (necessarily orientable) smooth $2$-manifolds are parallelizable?

I'm aware that the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not parallelizable, whereas the torus $\mathbb{T}^2 = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ is.  This leaves the case of connected sums of tori $\Sigma_g = \mathbb{T}^2 \# \cdots \# \mathbb{T}^2$.

Note: This is not a homework question.  I'm asking purely out of curiosity, especially because I have no idea how one would approach this problem (aside from the techniques [mentioned in this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/which-manifolds-are-parallelizable), which are slightly above my level).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $S$ is a parallelizable surface, then it has a flat Riemannian metric -- just choose a smooth global frame and declare it to be orthonormal.  If in addition $S$ is compact, Gauss-Bonnet implies that it has Euler characteristic zero.  The only compact orientable surface with $\chi(S)=0$ is the torus.

Comment: That's a nice argument. Thanks, Jack. Any new books on the way? :-)

Comment: @JesseMadnick -- I'm working on a second edition of my Riemannian Manifolds book. No promises, but I hope it will be ready for publication by the end of 2014.  (Also, I just published a new book called [_Axiomatic Geometry_](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=AMSTEXT-21), meant for a course in geometry for future high-school teachers.)

Comment: What about the Klein bottle?

Comment: @EduardoLonga: Sorry, since the OP said he was restricting attention to orientable surfaces, those are the only ones I was thinking about. But I should have said that. Now fixed.