# Is T($S^2 \times S^1$) trivial?

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles

How would I find out if  T($S^2 \times S^1$) is trivial or not?

Using the hairy ball theorem I can show that  T($S^2$) is not trivial, and it is straight forward to show that  T($S^1$) is trivial.

But I have no idea about          T($S^2 \times S^1$).

I know that T($S^2 \times S^1$)$\cong$ T($S^2)\times$T($S^1$). I tried to say something about restricting a global frame to $S^2$ and deriving a contradiction, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Think normal bundles.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Sorry, I am really having a lot of trouble understanding this. Can you give me more.

Comment: Do you agree that the sum of the tangent bundle on $S^2$ and the normal bundle on $S^2$ is trivial? If so, find a way to get the normal bundle in there from what you've got! If not... convince yourself. :)

Comment: Even if I believe that the sum is trivial, (I'm not convinced of that yet) how does this help me solve the problem? Is there some way I can relate the tangent bundle of the product to the sum of the bundles on $S^2$?

Comment: Even more: all oriented 3-manifolds are parallelizable, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/which-manifolds-are-parallelizable.

Comment: @Georges: Mike is referring to the normal bundle of $S^2$ in $\Bbb R^3$. The big hint is $T(S^1)$ *is* trivial so $T(S^2\times S^1)\cong T(S^2)\oplus\epsilon^1$, where $\epsilon^1$ is the trivial line bundle on $S^2$. ... But I will comment that it's not difficult to write down *explicitly* three everywhere linearly independent vector fields on $S^2\times S^1$, once again using the standard embedding of $S^2\subset\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Dear @Ted: yes, I know the idea but you are equating a bundle on $S^2\times S^1$ with a bundle on $S^2$ in your isomorphism. That  abuse of language may be confusing for a beginner. I encourage you to  write a complete answer, with the suitable pull-backs explicitly displayed, and I will gladly upvote you (and Bates would probably accept your answer...) .

Comment: I think it would help me a lot if someone wrote a complete answer.

Comment: Sorry for confusing others with my comments.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 8):

Let $p_1, p_2$ be the respective projection onto $S^1$ and $S^2$. Canonically we have $T(S^1 \times S^2) \cong p_1^{-1}T(S^1) \oplus p_2^{-1}T(S^2)$. As the tangent bundle of the circle is trivial, the former is isomorphic the trivial line bundle on $S^1 \times S^2$. Let $\xi$ be the trivial line bundle on $S^2$. Then this is again isomorphic to $p_2^{-1}T(S^2) \oplus p_2^{-1}(\xi) \cong p_2^{-1}(T(S^2) \oplus \xi)$. Consider $S^2$ as embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ in the standard manner; then it has trivial normal bundle (because there is a nonvanishing section of it), and $T(S^2) \oplus N(S^2) \cong S^2 \times \Bbb R^3$. So $$p_2^{-1}(T(S^2) \oplus \xi) \cong p_2^{-1}(T(S^2) \oplus N(S^2)) \cong p_2^{-1}(S^2 \times \Bbb R^3) \cong S^2 \times S^1 \times \Bbb R^3.$$ So the tangent bundle of $S^2 \times S^1$ is trivial.

Comment: A similar argument (you have to futz to get a copy of the trivial line bundle) works to show that $S^n \times S^k$ has trivial tangent bundle for $n$ odd.

Comment: +1 for the answer and the interesting comment (in which I made acquaintance with the verb "futz"). Did you learn about these parallelizable products of spheres in Hirsch  ? I did.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It's an exercise in Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" - before the author has introduced Whitney sums! (It's marked with a symbol that means 'come back later'.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Mike.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg And thank you for your kind comments.