# Manifolds with vanishing Stiefel-Whitney classes but are not stably parallelizable

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

It is known that if a manifold is stably parallelizable, then it's Stiefel-Whitney classes must vanish. Is the converse true?

Note that we know that the converse cannot hold if stably parallelizable is replaced parallelizable; for example, spheres are stably parallelizable and so have vanishing Stiefel-Whitney classes but are not parallelizable. Also, what is known about this question if we replace Stiefel-Whitney classes with other characteristic classes?

Comment: [Sutherland, W. A. "Vanishing of Stiefel-Whitney classes." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 31.2 (1972): 637.] notes that Atiyah and Hirzebruch have shown that S-W classes vanish for all vector bundles on the 9th suspension of every finite CW-complex.

Comment: @Mariano: but when is the 9th suspension of a finite CW complex both 1) a manifold and 2) not stably parallelizable?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/which-manifolds-are-parallelizable

Comment: An example of a non-stably trivial vector bundle with trivial Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin classes is given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/112764/21564).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The converse is not true. If a manifold is stably parallelizable, then its Pontryagin classes must also vanish, but the vanishing of the Stiefel-Whitney classes need not imply this.

For example, let $X$ be a closed simply connected smooth $4$-manifold. Since $X$ is simply connected, $w_1$ and $w_3$ automatically vanish. $w_4$ vanishes iff the Euler characteristic of $X$ is even iff $\dim H_2(X)$ is even. $w_2$ vanishes iff $X$ admits a spin structure iff the [intersection form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_form_%284-manifold%29) of $X$ is even. It follows that the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $X$ vanish iff its intersection form has even rank and even parity. But by the [Hirzebruch signature theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence#L_genus_and_the_Hirzebruch_signature_theorem), the Pontryagin class $p_1 \in H^4(X)$ vanishes iff the signature $\sigma(X)$ of the intersection form vanishes.

Hence to give a counterexample it suffices to find a closed simply connected smooth $4$-manifold $X$ whose intersection form has even rank, even parity, and nonzero signature. For example, you can take $X$ to be a [K3 surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface), or more explicitly a hypersurface of degree $4$ in $\mathbb{CP}^3$ (see, for example, the calculations in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/)), whose intersection form has rank $22$, even parity, and signature $-16$. By [Rokhlin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokhlin%27s_theorem) this is the smallest signature possible (in absolute value).

**Edit:** Incidentally, $4$ is the smallest possible dimension of a closed counterexample. If $X$ is a closed smooth $d$-manifold, $d \le 3$, then:

- When $d = 1$, $X$ is a disjoint union of circles and hence is parallelizable.
- When $d = 2$, if $w_1$ vanishes then $X$ is orientable, and this automatically implies that $w_2$ vanishes (e.g. because we know that the Euler characteristic is even in this case, but see [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/five-proofs-that-the-euler-characteristic-of-a-closed-orientable-surface-is-even/) for other arguments). But a closed orientable surface is stably parallelizable: in the usual embedding of such a surface into $\mathbb{R}^3$, the outward pointing normal trivializes the normal bundle.
- When $d = 3$, if $w_1$ vanishes then $X$ is orientable, and again this automatically implies that $w_2$ vanishes, now by some [Wu class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class#Wu_classes) computations. It follows that the classifying map of the tangent bundle $X \to BO(3)$ lifts to a map $X \to B \text{Spin}(3)$. But $B \text{Spin}(3)$ is $3$-connected, so any map to it from a $3$-manifold is nullhomotopic. Hence $X$ is not only stably parallelizable but parallelizable.

Comment: Thanks! What about when both the Stiefel-Whitney and the Pontryagin numbers vanish? Then the manifold must be null-cobordant but does this imply that the manifold is stably parallelizable?

Comment: @user39598: you need to be more careful with your wording here. The condition that characteristic *numbers* vanish is weaker than the condition that characteristic *classes* vanish, although the latter implies the former. And you should distinguish between being null-cobordant and being oriented null-cobordant. Anyway, I believe the answer is no, but I don't have a counterexample.

Comment: Here is a strategy for constructing a counterexample: suppose a smooth manifold $X$ admits a stable spin structure, or equivalently that the classifying map $X \to BO$ of its stable tangent bundle lifts to a map $X \to B \text{Spin}$. Now, $B \text{Spin}$ is $3$-connected with $\pi_4 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. There is a natural map $B \text{Spin} \to B^4 \mathbb{Z}$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_4$, and it gives a characteristic class of stable spin structures called the first fractional Pontryagin class $\frac{p_1}{2}$, so named because twice the class is the pullback of $p_1$.

Comment: This characteristic class vanishes iff $X \to B \text{Spin}$ lifts to the next step in the Whitehead tower (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Whitehead+tower) of $BO$, which is called $B \text{String}$ (see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+structure for details). In particular, if $H^4(X, \mathbb{Z})$ has $2$-torsion (so $\dim X \ge 5$) then it's possible that $p_1$ vanishes but that $\frac{p_1}{2}$ does not (and we can ignore the other Pontryagin classes if $\dim X \le 7$). But I can't complete the construction of a counterexample from here because I don't know how to compute $\frac{p_1}{2}$.

Comment: Incidentally, this argument shows that if $X$ is a closed smooth $4$-manifold whose Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin classes vanish, then $X$ is stably parallelizable. But I don't know what happens when $\dim X \ge 5$.

Comment: sorry, I thought that I had a counterexample because I thought that a map that induces zero on cohomology is null-homotopic, which would help show that if the characteristic classes are zero, the bundle would be stably trivial. Even if your example holds, I am interested in whether there are conditions (maybe stronger than vanishing of characteristic classes) that would allow one to conclude that a manifold is stably parallelizable.

Comment: @user39598: the conditions *are* given by vanishing of characteristic classes, but as the manifolds get higher dimensional the characteristic classes get more complicated. In the above answer characteristic classes settle the question for closed $2, 3$-manifolds and $\frac{p_1}{2}$ is a new characteristic class, only defined in the presence of a stable spin structure, that obstructs string structures and that settles the question for closed $4, 5, 6, 7$-manifolds. For closed $8$-manifolds there is yet another new characteristic class $\frac{p_2}{6}$, the second fractional Pontryagin class...

Comment: ...only defined in the presence of a stable string structure, and that settles the question. For closed $9$-manifolds there is yet another new characteristic class, and so forth. There is a general framework here involving lifts of a map $X \to Y$ through the Whitehead tower of $Y$ (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Whitehead+tower); the obstructions at each step are cohomology classes in $H^n(X, \pi_n(Y))$, only defined if the previous obstruction vanishes.

Comment: If you'd like to continue this I think you should ask a new question.